# How to join 3 tables into one with these tables having foreign key to a fourth table?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

kit

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | protocol         | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                | detail_service   | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | date_conclusion  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                | resp_key         | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

doc

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |auto_increment | employee_key        | varchar(10) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | doc_total           | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | date_doc            | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                +---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

srv

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | employee_key      | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | srv_total         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | date_srv          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

key_e

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| key               | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| login_employee    | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

employee

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| login      | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have these 5 tables. I want a result like with these fields:

```
 employee.login, employee.name, SUM(kit.detail_service LIKE '%Deal%') AS 'Deal', SUM(kit.detail_service LIKE '%Not Deal%') AS 'Not Deal', SUM(kit.detail_service LIKE '%Postponed%') AS 'Postponed',
```

SUM(doc.doc_total) AS 'DOC', SUM(srv.srv_cheque) AS 'SRV'

key_e.k: Foreign key to employee.login
kit.resp_key: Foreign key to key_e
doc.employee_key/srv.employee_key: Foreign key to key_e (both of these 2 are equals, but different of kit.resp_key)

The query I made:

```
SELECT
    e.login,
    e.name,
    (SELECT SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Deal%') FROM kit k WHERE k.resp_key=key_e.key) AS 'Deal',
    (SELECT SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Not Deal%') FROM kit k WHERE k.resp_key=key_e.key) AS 'Not Deal',
    (SELECT SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Postponed%') FROM kit k WHERE k.resp_key=key_e.key) AS 'Postponed',
    (SELECT SUM(doc_total) FROM doc WHERE doc.employee_key=key_e.key) AS 'DOC',
    (SELECT SUM(srv_total) FROM srv WHERE srv.employee_key=key_e.key) AS 'SRV'
FROM
    employee e
INNER JOIN key_e ON
    e.login = key_e.login_employee
GROUP BY e.login, key_e.key
```

========================================

The query that I made returns me almost everything I want, except for the rows are duplicated. Because of KIT's key and SRV's and DOC's key are different, the result duplicates. I don't know how to join the row with SRV's and DOC's key with KIT's key. The structure is kind a messy and maybe using 'join' will solve it, but I don't know how. I did some queries using 'join' and not this inner select, but no success so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want two levels of aggregation.  In particular, you want to aggregate at the key level *before* doing the joins.  Then you want to aggregate at the login level:

```
SELECT e.login, e.name,
       SUM(kit.num_Deal) as num_Deal,
       SUM(kit.num_not_deal) as num_not_deal,
       SUM(kit.num_Postponed) as num_Postponed,
       SUM(doc_total) as doc_total,
       SUM(srv_total) as srv_total
FROM employee e INNER JOIN
     key_e ON
     ON e.login = key_e.login_employee LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT doc.employee_key, SUM(doc.doc_total) as doc_total
      FROM doc
      GROUP BY doc.employee_key
     ) doc
     ON doc.employee_key = key_e.key LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT srv.employee_key, SUM(srv.srv_total) as srv_total
      FROM srv
      GROUP BY srv.employee_key
     ) srv
     ON srv.employee_key = key_e.key LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT kit.employee_key, 
             SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Deal%') as num_Deal,
             SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Not Deal%') as num_not_deal,
             SUM(k.detail_service LIKE '%Postponed%') as Postponed
      FROM kit k
      GROUP BY kit.employee_key
     ) kit
     ON kit.resp_key = key_e.key
GROUP BY e.login, e.name
```

Comment: thank you Gordon. Thanks for the answer that works perfectly and thanks for editing my question, that it wasn't formatted